# Intuitive statistics book

Tags: references, intuition

I am looking for a statistics book that not only gives formulas or proofs but also gives intuitive explanations.

For example, the standard deviation is defined by

${\sigma_x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {{x_i} - \overline x } \right)} ^2}}$.

I am wondering why it's not defined by $\frac{1}{n}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n |{ {x_i} - \overline x }}|$ instead?. The absolute mean deviation is not used that much. Both quantities are nonnegative and can model a distance to the mean. The standard deviation definition gives more weight to points that are very far from the mean and less weight to the points that are too close to the mean; because squaring a number between 0 and 1 makes it smaller and squaring a number that is greater than 1 makes it larger. The absolute mean deviation does not have this amplification/reduction effect, so why we don't use it more often?

I am looking for a book that explains this kind of stuff.

Background: Bachelor in mathematics (but that was long time ago, my daily job is programming now)

PS: I am NOT looking for an answer on mean absolute deviation vs standard deviation. It's just an example that illustrates what "intuitive" means to me. My question is about reference recommendations.

Comment: I know you're asking for a book that answers this question, not an answer to the question itself. But for completeness, this question is answered here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118

Comment: We have many, many threads about [tag:references]. Here's a search to help you get started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20answers%3a1%20score%3a3%20beginner

Comment: @Sycorax I ooked into a lot of threads, (e.g.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/book-for-broad-and-conceptual-overview-of-statistical-methods). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a book that satisfies my criteria.

Comment: It's possible that such a book does not exist, and learning the answer to this specific question would require a deep enough knowledge of statistics to draw connections between concepts. The thread addressing your sample question points in that direction: the central limit theorem is the reason square, not absolute, deviations from the mean are useful.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "this kind of stuff."  *Every* introductory stats textbook deals with quantities like standard deviations and most, if not all, attempt to give clear "intuitive" explanations for their intended audiences.  Please clarify how your inquiry would not be satisfied by a list of introductory textbooks.

Comment: @whuber Most books give explanations of the **What** and not the **Why**. For example, I couldn't find any book that explains why the standard deviation is much more used than the absolute mean deviation

Comment: You seem to be setting impossible conditions on any book: exactly what alternatives to the SD ought to be discussed, for instance?  The list would be endless.  Most books do attempt to explain the why, but at varying levels of sophistication.  That's why we have many threads that list textbooks, because they are aimed at different readers.  You are likely to find useful information faster by consulting some of those threads.

Comment: @PhilippeLafourcade Take a look at the chapter 1 of E. L. Lehmann - 1991 - Theory of Point Estimation-Springer US. I think it gives a cool overview about a lot of introductory statistics that is used but not "justified" in basic classes.

Comment: [This site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20book%20wiki%3ayes%20is%3aquestion) will be useful.  Make sure to check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48347.